# Jenkins - how to prevent jobs from running on specific slave

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I have a requirement where i need to run Jenkins job which will run some integration tests, as those integration tests needs some services which are only available on one specific slave, i want to make sure that particular job run only on that slave.

Lets say i have job-1, job-2, job-3 and slave-1 to salve-20
I want to make sure only job-1 can run on slave-1 and All other jobs (job-2,job-3) can run on any salve but not slave-1

I can achieve one part of it by enabling the option: "Restrict where this project can be run" so job-1 will always run on slave-1

The question is how to restrict other jobs from running on slave-1.

Answer (score 6):

For this purpose I think its best to restrict from the perspective of the node instead of restricting all jobs.
When opening the node configuration, you can specify how this node shall be used. The default is to use it as much as possible (in order to automatically reduce the load on the master itself).
However what we use in such scenario, is to use this node only if the job to be run defined this as its desired node to run on.

[image: Jenkins node configuration]

For example we have a node to run our UI tests. And it shall run UI tests only not anything else. The jobs specifying the UI tests have this node set in their label expression, all other jobs have an empty expression - meaning they could run anywhere - but the node configuration restricts any other job to be run on that node.

Answer (score 1):

Following on Behe's answer of using the Label Expression, you can also [image: Restrict Where the Job is Run] using the label filters.

Answer (score 0):

*Label Expressions* support operators that are very powerful. E.g., NOT using slave-1 would be:

```
!slave-1
```

Comment: But in this case i need to update all jobs and add !slave-1, also i will have to make sure every new job has this Label Expression

Comment: Then you might want to update your question to include your requirements